# Why is Wordpress is hosted with no styling (css)?

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp

Hi I am hosting a wordpress powered site locally on an xampp stack. Viewing `http://localhost` I can see styling ans css but when I go to the site where I host, the content is there but nos styling or css.

Is it not configured correctly, where should I go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Wordpress admin go to *Settings* > *General* and check the *Wordpress Address* and *Site Address*

Comment: Thank. From the Wordpress admin go to Settings > General
and set the _Wordpress Address_ and _Site Address_ to: `http://www.number1.co.za`

Comment: This should've been a comment.